# Transform pivoted table into database structure

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table structure as follows:

```
|      Category       |      Sector      |     01/01/2024   |     01/02/2024   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         car         |   Financial      |         34       |         30       |
|         bike        |   Financial      |         42       |         33       |
```

The table is pivoted, where each column represents a month of the year. The table is obtained through an importRange and I need to transform it into a database structure, resulting in the columns: Category, Sector, Date, Value. Thus, each combination of value and date will be represented by a line.

How can I do this?The new table can be structured in a new tab.

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that the community can use to see what you'd like to do? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. Like a dummy sheet so we can visualize and replicate what you have. You may include your desired output in it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REDUCE and VSTACK:

```
=REDUCE({"Category","Sector","Date","Value"},C2:D,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="",a,
VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX(A:B,ROW(v)),INDEX(1:1,COLUMN(v)),v)))))
```

Change `C2:D` to the range of where you have the values (without the headers and without those first two columns). Then it will go through each value and the first two columns based on the row, and the header of the date depending on the column of that value:

[image]